# Is there a way to edit the new object menu in blender 2.83.5?

Tags: objects, interface

I've been enjoying the new features and stability of blender 2.83.5, however I discovered an issue. Normally when you create a new object in your scene a menu appears to offer options on the object. I am getting this menu however it is entirely grayed out and uneditable. If anyone knows something about the new version having either a bug or new way of working I'd be very appreciative of any info.[image: Grayed out and uneditable (more objects than just torus)]

Comment: it may be because Global Undo is deactivate in the Preferences > System > Memory & Limits

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that. Yeah that was the issue, thanks!

Comment: nobody can guess   ;)   I don't even know why Global Undo does that